# How to load theme style(s) in CKEditor?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

In Drupal 8, how can you have CKEditor load additional stylesheets when using a configured filter format? In Drupal 7, you could give the WYSIWYG module paths to CSS sheets to load, which made the editor text reflect the theme as much as possible. I am not seeing this option.

Answer (score 15):

Here is one way to do it... not sure if there are others (admin based):

```
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Implements hook_ckeditor_css_alter().
 *
 * Injects our CSS sheets anytime CKEditor has loaded.
 *
 * @param array $css
 * @param Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor $editor
 */
function mymodule_ckeditor_css_alter(array &$css, Editor $editor) {
  if (!$editor->hasAssociatedFilterFormat()) {
    return;
  }

  $known_formats = [
    'basic_html',
    'full_html'
  ];

  if (in_array($editor->getFilterFormat()->id(), $known_formats)) {
    $css[] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/build/css/style.css';
  }
}
```

Comment: before function, use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor; is needed.

Answer (score 14):

Unless you want to load styles for specific formats, you can easily add CSS within your `MODULE.info.yml` file, like so:

```
ckeditor_stylesheets:
  - css/application.css
  - css/ckeditor.css
```

Use `@import` statements inside one of the stylesheets to pull in external stylesheets not in your theme:

```
/* in css/ckeditor.css */
@import url('//mycdn.com/myfonts.css');
@import url('/path/to/drupal/module/styles.css');
```

Comment: I discovered a workaround to include external stylesheets using an `@import` statement.

Comment: Yes, you can use standard CSS import `@import url("http://example.com/file.css");`

Comment: Works in Drupal 9.3. It's hard to believe it was that easy!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple solution for this in Drupal 8, when you are using a custom theme or custom admin theme.

1. Open your custom theme info file ***.info.yml** and add the line above `libraries` or below `base_theme`.

   ```
   ckeditor_stylesheets:
     - css/ckeditor.css
   ```
2. Create a file **ckeditor.css** in the `css/` directory.
3. Write your CSS in that file and the styles will be applied to CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom CSS with something like this. You can add your custom CSS to `editor.css`.

```
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

function MYMODULE_ckeditor_css_alter(array &$css, Editor $editor) {
  $css[] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/ckeditor/moono_dark/editor.css';
}
```

This page was one of the top hits for theming a Drupal CKEditor skin too

I was able to change the skin with this code from Drupal.org. You can load Moono Dark with something like this. You can put it in your custom module's `.module` file.

You will have to change the URL below based on where you download the skin, but you get the idea.

```
function MYMODULE_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {
  foreach (array_keys($settings['editor']['formats']) as $text_format_id) {
    if ($settings['editor']['formats'][$text_format_id]['editor'] === 'ckeditor') {
      $settings['editor']['formats'][$text_format_id]['editorSettings']['skin'] = 'Moono Dark,https://www.example.com/modules/custom/MYMODULE/ckeditor/moono_dark/editor.css';
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/ckeditor-api/overview